# ReactJS: How to load SVG dynamically from an const object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, svg

I'm trying to load SVG's dynamically via a const object to easily reuse in other blocks.
But the SVG doens't show.

When i import the svg in the top and load it in `<Img src='../../images/svg-1.svg' />` its working but i wanted to import it dynamically to reuse it and change svg easily in the others blocks.

Please check the codes below:

Data.js

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: 'about',
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: 'Premium Bank',
  headLine: 'Unlimited Transactions with zero fees',
  description: 'Get access to our exclusive app that allows you to send unlmited transactions without getting charged any fees.',
  buttonLabel: 'Get started',
  imgStart: false,
  img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg'),
  alt: 'Car',
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false
}
```

InfoSection.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '../ButtonCSS';
import {
  InfoContainer,
  InfoWrapper,
  InfoRow,
  Column1,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Subtitle,
  BtnWrap,
  ImgWrap,
  Column2,
  Img,
} from './InfoSectionCSS';

const InfoSection = ({
  lightBg,
  id,
  imgStart,
  topLine,
  lightText,
  headLine,
  darkText,
  description,
  buttonLabel,
  img,
  alt,
  primary,
  dark,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
        <InfoWrapper>
          <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
            <Column1>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headLine}</Heading>
                <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <BtnWrap>
                  <Button
                    to='home'
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={500}
                    spy={true}
                    exact='true'
                    offset={-80}
                    dark={dark}
                    primary={primary}
                  >
                    {buttonLabel}
                  </Button>
                </BtnWrap>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
              <ImgWrap>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrap>
            </Column2>
          </InfoRow>
        </InfoWrapper>
      </InfoContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfoSection;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import HeroSection from '../components/HeroSection/Hero';
import InfoSection from '../components/InfoSection/InfoSection';
import { homeObjOne, homeObjTwo, homeObjThree } from '../components/InfoSection/Data';

const Home = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
      <HeroSection />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjOne} />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjTwo} />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjThree} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The SVG should be in the right side.
[image: Result1]

Comment: Can you upload Img component too.

Comment: @PramodKumar it is in the Data.js

img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg'),

in the InfoSection.js i tried to load in with <Img src={img} alt={alt} />

Comment: You can import svg as js object - `import svg1 from '../../images/svg-1.svg'` and assign it to the key - `img: svg1,`

Comment: @user2819542 check the anwser, i solved it but thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to solve it.

just added .default behind `img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg')` like so `img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg').default,`

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: 'about',
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: 'Premium Bank',
  headLine: 'Unlimited Transactions with zero fees',
  description: 'Get access to our exclusive app that allows you to send unlmited transactions without getting charged any fees.',
  buttonLabel: 'Get started',
  imgStart: false,
  img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg').default,
  alt: 'Car',
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false
}
```